# How to write code to display alphabets and their numerical score in swift 5 using viewController

Tags: swift, uikit, textfield

How to check the string of input `UITextfield` given by user is a part of string array or not. If it is a part of array, how to display its value in `UITextfield`?
For example, a user put is "r" in the `UITextField`. It should be a part of alphabet string array, if not display an error. If it is a part of string array display its dictionary value in another `UITextfield`

```swift
var alphabet: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

var alphaDictionary = [String: Int]()
for val in 1...alphabet.count {
    var i: Int = 1
    for a in alphabet {
        alphaDictionary[a] = i
        i += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also build that dictionary with `let dictionary = alphabet.enumerated().reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1.element] = $1.offset + 1 }`. Or, if you don’t need the numeric value, but want to enjoy the O(1) lookup speed (not that it matters with a collection this small), use a set, e.g, `let set = Set(alphabet)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that making your view controller implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` which will receive the input. This delegate will validate the input and either display the alert with error or update the `secondTextField` with the value that you have mapped:

```swift
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let validInput = alphabet.contains(string)
        if validInput {
            let score = textField.text!.reduce(0) { $0 + alphaDictionary[String($1)]! }
            resultView.text = textField.text! + String(score)
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid character", message: "The character you entered is not part of the alphabet", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return validInput
    }
}
```

Make sure you set your view controller as delegate of that `UITextField`:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: @RadhikaChilukuri You were not clear with that in your question. Does this solve it? Please accept the answer or describe more what's the issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to show alphabet and its numerical value in a textView. At the same time I am adding up all numerical values of word. For eg., "hello", its value is 52. I am trying to display score also in the same textView. But its not happening. Please help me with this

Comment: @RadhikaChilukuri I updated my answer. The word plus the score will be displayed on the `resultView` by concatenating the two strings: `resultView.text = textField.text! + String(score)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @IBAction func goTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let inputLetter = (userAlphabet.text!)
           let inputWord = (userWord.text!)
            let word = inputWord.map({String($0)})
            if alphabet.contains(inputLetter) {
               // it exists, do something
                for val in 1...alphabet.count {
                var i: Int = 1
    for a in alphabet {
               alphaDictionary[a] = i
               i += 1
                   }
               }
        let alpha = inputLetter
resultView.text = String(alphaDictionary[alpha]!)

Here it displays both alphabet and its value in textview
        
for ele in word{
                    
                print(alphaDictionary[ele]!)
                    score += alphaDictionary[ele]!
                    }
            resultView.text = inputWord
            resultView.text = String(score)
```

here it displays word's score, but not both. How to append another set of data to a textView

Comment: You should edit your question and update it with this information there.